# Facebook Promotion guidelines

Tags: facebook, legal

Hi I want to build a Facebook `promotional/competition` page and just want to make 100% sure that I am within the laws governed by the Facebook Promotional Guidelines.

Here is a link to the guidelines

http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

I want to build a video voting page on Facebook.
Facebook users cannot enter the competition. 
They can however vote for their favourite video and on voting post a message to their wall.

The video with the most votes will be declared the wining video.

edited

A random voter could also stand a chance on winning a prize.

here is an extract from the guidelines that i am unclear about.

`3.  You must not use Facebook features or functionality as a promotion’s registration or entry mechanism.  For example, the act of liking a Page or checking in to a Place cannot automatically register or enter a promotion participant. 
This is pretty self explanatory. Thus we cannot ask someone to “like” or vote for their favourite video in order to enter or a stand a chance to win. We can ask them to do these things, but not as a condition to be part of the competition.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of 'liking' a page or checking in to a place cannot automatically register or enter a promotion participant.
which just means that someone can not enter a promotion just by liking a page, and win something for just liking a page.
I don't think you would violate any terms for doing what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks I have just been informed that the voters could also stand a chance of winning a prize. Would that be violating the terms

Comment: with how i read the part you pasted, yes it would violate the terms